# How to doubleclick on an input text box which is written using JavaScript (bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, double-click

How can I double-click on an `input-text-box` or a `text-box`, which (i.e. `input-text-box` or `text-box`) has been written using bootstrap.

Also, when I try to open chrome browser through selenium, this page of mine become unclickable even manually!

For my purpose, when I double-click an `input-text-box` or a `text-box`, it  should open up a `modal-box` wherein I can write my desired value.

```java
IWebElement test1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@title, 'SomeText')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.DoubleClick(test1).Perform();


alert.SendKeys("");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.DoubleClick(test1).Perform();
```

Comment: Is it a public url? If yes, can you please share the link.

Comment: Hello, No it is not a public URL. So I cannot share it

Comment: Have you tried in firefox browser using gecko driver, do you see the same unclickable  behavior?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to navigate to my said URL using gecko driver in Firefox. I am not able to find reasons or solutions for this problem. Can you help?

Comment: How about IE browser?